# Error during connect on docker windows - must be run with elevated privileges to connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Windows version: Windows 10 Home
Command run: *docker version*

Hi, any ways to solve the below error. I have tried uninstalling for many times and it does not work. Hope for help. Thanks in advance.

```
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:58:50 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Comment: Try running the console as administrator before executing your command. Moreover, it isn't recommendable to install Docker over Windows 10 Home (https://medium.com/@mbyfieldcameron/docker-on-windows-10-home-edition-c186c538dff3), though it's possible. You can check this other post to deep on the issue: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-10-home-edition/.

Comment: @Roberto C. Rodriguez-Hidalgo Thanks so much for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The problem was because I was using the version Docker Desktop 4.10.1. I downgraded to version Docker Desktop 4.9.1. Now, docker works.

Here you can find old version of docker desktop.

[Old version docker to download](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-491)

Comment: what if i see same error, but docker desktop is not even installed?